# Unable to read value of dom element after populating it by Javascript

Tags: javascript

I have 2 javascript functions. One writes two values on the page and the second tries to read those values. The problem is that the second function is not able to read those values - it says "undefined".

the functions are:

```
<html>
<body onload="generate()">
<p>
 <a type="number" id="first"></a>
 <a>+</a>
 <a type="number" id="second"></a>
 <a>=</a>
 <input type="number" id="result"></input>
 <button id="submit" onclick="dosome()">Submit</button>
<p id="super"></p>



<script>
var press_flag ="no";
var press_flag ="no";
function generate()
{
    var x = Math.round(Math.random()*100);
    var y = Math.round(Math.random()*100);
    document.getElementById("first").innerHTML = x;
    document.getElementById("second").innerHTML = y;
    var result = document.getElementById("result").value;

    setTimeout(function () {
    alert(press_flag);
    if (press_flag == "yes")
    {}
    else
    {
    document.getElementById("submit").disabled = true;
    var result = x+y;
    document.getElementById("super").innerHTML = result;
    }

    }, 7000);
}

function dosome()
{
   press_flag= "yes";
   alert(document.getElementById("first").value);
   var a = document.getElementById("first").value;
   var b = document.getElementById("second").value;
   var c = document.getElementById("result").value;
   var resultfinal = Number(a) + Number(b);
   if (c==resultfinal)
   {
     document.getElementById("super").innerHTML = "Superb my boy!";
   }

}
</script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: what is the dom element for these ids`first` & `second`.Can you please share the html?

Comment: Could you please share the html file

Comment: added the full code

Answer (score 0):

It works for me,you can check it:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
 first:<br>
 <input type="text" name="firstname" id="first"><br>
  second:<br>
  <input type="text" name="lastname" id="second">
  <input type="text" value="result" id="result">
  <input type="text" id="super">
  <input type="submit" value="submit" id="submit" onclick="generate()">
  <input type="submit" onclick="dosome()">

</body>
</html>
<script>
var press_flag ="no";
function generate()
{
    var x = Math.round(Math.random()*100);
    var y = Math.round(Math.random()*100);
    document.getElementById("first").innerHTML = x;
    document.getElementById("second").innerHTML = y;
    var result = document.getElementById("result").value;

    setTimeout(function () {
    alert(press_flag);
    if (press_flag == "yes")
    {}
    else
    {
    document.getElementById("submit").disabled = true;
    var result = x+y;
    document.getElementById("super").innerHTML = result;
    }

    }, 7000);
}

function dosome()
{
   press_flag= "yes";
   alert(document.getElementById("first").value);
   var a = document.getElementById("first").value;
   var b = document.getElementById("second").value;
   var c = document.getElementById("result").value;
   var resultfinal = Number(a) + Number(b);
   if (c==resultfinal)
   {
     document.getElementById("super").innerHTML = "Superb my boy!";
   }

}
</script>
```

It does not show any undefined.